# PHP llamada a constante de clase interpretando su nombre desde el contenido de una variable

Tags: php

Tengo este código:

```
if (!empty($filters['status'])) {
    if ($filters['status'] == 'DRAFT') {
        $query .= " AND r.status = :status";
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_DRAFT;
        $paramTypes[':status'] = \PDO::PARAM_STR;
    } elseif ($filters['status'] == 'READY_FOR_REVIEW') {
        $query .= " AND r.status = :status";
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_READY_FOR_REVIEW;
        $paramTypes[':status'] = \PDO::PARAM_STR;
    } elseif ($filters['status'] == 'REJECTED') {
        $query .= " AND r.status = :status";
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_REJECTED;
        $paramTypes[':status'] = \PDO::PARAM_STR;
    } elseif ($filters['status'] == 'APPROVED') {
        $query .= " AND r.status = :status";
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_APPROVED;
        $paramTypes[':status'] = \PDO::PARAM_STR;
    } elseif ($filters['status'] == 'VALIDATED') {
        $query .= " AND r.status = :status";
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_VALIDATED;
        $paramTypes[':status'] = \PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
}
```

He querido simplificarlo. He sacado las asignaciones de `$query` y `$paramTypes` fuera de los ifs:

```
if (!empty($filters['status'])) {
    $query .= "AND r.status = :status";
    $paramTypes[':status'] = \PDO::PARAM_STR;

    if ($filters['status'] == 'DRAFT') {
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_DRAFT;
    } elseif ($filters['status'] == 'READY_FOR_REVIEW') {
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_READY_FOR_REVIEW;
    } elseif ($filters['status'] == 'REJECTED') {
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_REJECTED;
    } elseif ($filters['status'] == 'APPROVED') {
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_APPROVED;
    } elseif ($filters['status'] == 'VALIDATED') {
        $paramValues[':status'] = Report::STATUS_VALIDATED;
    }
}
```

Dado que en todos los casos, en `$filters['status']` siempre llega un texto en mayúsculas, que coincide con la ultima parte de las constantes que tengo definidas en la clase Report, he pensado en componer el nombre de la constante a raíz del valor de `$filters`. Para ello, hago lo siguiente:

```
$state = "STATUS_" . $filters['status'];
$paramValues[':status'] = Report::$state;
```

Sin embargo, esto da error:

> Access to undeclared static property: Report::$state

Es decir, esoty intentando acceder a la propiedad `$state` en lugar de interpretar el texto que tengo en la variable.

¿Es posible componer el nombre de una constante de alguna manera?

Comment: Como que no me he enterado bien de la cuestión. ¿`$state` es un miembro  de la clase `Report`? Si es así, ¿cómo la tienes declarada dentro de la clase?

Comment: @a.Cedano $state no esta definida en la clase Report.  es una variable que monto antes de llamar a Report::$state, intentando que interpretara el contenido y llamara a la constante que yo queria. Pero en lugar de eso se interpreta como una propiedad estatica, cosa que no es lo que quiero. La solución de marcos.gallardo es la respuesta en este caso.

Comment: Ok. No le veo mucho sentido a eso que quieres hacer. Cuando otro programador vea eso, o tú mismo al cabo de un tiempo,  pensará que estás llamando a un miembro de Report cuando es una variable ¿ficticia podríamos decir?

Comment: Supón que mañana añadimos otro estado, STATUS_PAID. ¿Tengo que añadir otro if en la comprobación de filtros? El objetivo es que la validación no dependa de añadir elementos. la idea de usar Report::$state es erronea, cierto, pero porque no sabia como hacerlo. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la función [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.constant.php) de la siguiente forma:

```
$state = "STATUS_" . $filters['status'];
$paramValues[':status'] = constant('Report::'.$state);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/AUBRI52002)</kbd>